# Как правильно записать значения в таблицу?

Tags: lua

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая переводит с десятичной системы в римскую. Но я не уверена, правильно ли я создала массив. Мне нужно, чтобы я с помощью десятичного значения могла получить аргмумент в римской системе.

```lua
local mapping = { 
    [1000] = "M", 
    [900] = "CM", 
    [500] = "D",
    [400] = "CD",
    [100] = "C",
    [90] = "XC", 
    [50] = "L",
    [40] = "XL",
    [10] = "X",
    [9] = "IX",
    [5]= "V",
    [4] = "IV", 
    [1] = "I",
}
```

Правильно  ли я создала массив? Если правильно, то как правильно получать значение?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас числа, то так и доставайте:

```lua
print(mapping[1])
-- Output:
--   I

print(mapping[1000])
-- Output:
--   M
```

Если у вас строки с числами, то сначала конвертируйте:

```lua
print(mapping[tonumber("1")])
-- Output:
--   I

print(mapping[tonumber("1000")])
-- Output:
--   M
```